# iCal format for recurring events with start time and end time

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

Let's say I want to schedule a team meeting every monday at 10 am to 5pm. What would be the ical format for this schedule?

So far I have this but am not sure how to indicate the end time. Considering the event recurs forever

`DTSTART:19971022T100000
 RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO`

Comment: you need to specify a `DTEND` to specify the length of the meeting, otherwise it will be a 1 day long meeting

Comment: @oberron Thanks for your response.  I got mixed up between RRULE and VEVENT not sure if adding DTEND to RRULE will be syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your confusion here is a possible `VEVENT` example:

`BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uuid@yourdomain.com
DTSTART:19971022T100000
DTEND:19971022T170000
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO
END:VEVENT`

also keep in mind that as per the RFC5545, the first instance will be included in the list of occurences (with your example a [Wednesday](http://takemeback.to/22-October-1997#.V4PHivl96Uk)).